# Neural Network with an input array of size 4 and output array of size 8

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to process the data obtained from YOLO v5, which is an array of 4 values (posX, posY, SizX, Sizy) per object detected. Now, I know several detections are related, and I want a neural network to find this relation. For every array input, it should return as output a 2x4 matrix, or, flattened, an array of size 8. I am training 4017 samples using Keras Sequential model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu", name="layer1"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(592, activation="relu", name="layer2"))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=model.fit(X, y, batch_size=48, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

But the results I am getting are not good:

```
Epoch 20/20
80/80 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5413 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.5414 - val_accuracy: 0.9937
```

Where the predictions are:

```
Input: [0.50070833 0.50070833 0.42683333 0.22983333]

Expected Output: [[0.591      0.50070833 0.04514583 0.25035417]
                 [0.50070833 0.34475    0.44735417 0.04514583]]

NeuralNetwork Output: [[0.28618604 0.18969838 0.00889739 0.06283922]
                      [0.18952993 0.09904755 0.15489812 0.00890343]]
```

Adding/suppresing layers/BatchNormalization/Dropout is not making any difference and changing lossfunction/optimizer is only worsening the result. Do you have any advice or solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you given some thought on why you are using a softmax activation at the output layer? And how that affects predictions?

Comment: Wow! What can I say... The only thing I did not thought about changing was the activation, and now using softplus the results are almost identical to the expected ones! Thank you very much Dr.Snoopy!

Comment: @JavierVillena, glad it worked out. Please feel free to put an answer to your own question (preferable with a code) so that others can find the solution if they get similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Softmax activation at the output is used for classification problems, you do not seem to be doing classification, but regression (since the output is continuous, not discrete).

Then you should change your activation at the output to something appropriate, like `linear` (general solution) or `sigmoid` (if the targets are in the [0, 1] range).